# Storage Pool Server 2016 Hard Disk Not recognized

Tags: windows, storage, windows-server-2016, storage-spaces

I have a HP xw6600 server that is really old, but for the past year I've had 2016 Storage server installed with (2) 5TB drives being mirrored in a storage pool.  Recently we had a power outage and one of the drives started having IO errors and took the entire pool down which was disappointing.  I ordered the exact same drive on amazon to replace the failed drive and after receiving the new drive I have been unable to get windows to recognized this drive as a 5 TB drive.  It keeps saying its 561.40 GB. The other drive shows up in the physical drive list as 4.55, but the new one does not.  The drives I'm using are: HDWE150XZSTA.  The ONLY difference is the date on the drive.  Firmware, rev, everything else is identical!  Is there something I have to do in order to get Windows Storage Server to recognize this drive at the correct size?  I have updated the BIOS to the most recent version and it still shows all the drives as 561.40, but like I said windows gets the old drive size correct for some reason, but no the new drive?!?

Disk Management Shows my new good 5TB drive ask Disk 1, but as 561.40 GB and Disk 4 is the virtual disk.  Disk 4 is offline because of "critical write failures". All these drives are exactly the same except the manufacture date.

[image: Disk Management]

View from Server manager showing my virtual disk.

[image: Disks]

[image: Storage Pools]

Comment: Does any other OS or even Windows version properly recognize the drive?

Comment: Yes. I put it in my newer computer running Windows 10 and it worked fine.

Comment: Look for jumpers?  I'd also run `diskmgmt.msc` as administrator on your Windows 10 computer and see what it shows.  There's also Toshiba's diagnostic tool:  https://cdgenp01.csd.toshiba.com/content/support/downloads/ToshibaStorageDiagnosticTool.exe

Comment: @AndrewHenle really appreciate the help, but I've tried the diagnostic tool and it doesn't install.  Give me an error when installing.  Also, I have ran disk management and it shows up as 561.40 GB.